# Adding Enum dropdownlist value to database (MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, enums

I'm new to MVC5. I have a dropdownlist that I created using enum values that works perfectly. However, I am unable to get the value the user selects from the dropdownlist into the database table (SQLserver). Here is the enum...

```
[Required]
    public ClassTypeEnum Level { get; set; }

    public enum ClassTypeEnum
    {                        
        Junior = 0,
        Kindergarten = 1,
        Primary = 2            
    }
```

Initially, I had just one column in the table (Name) but when I created the dropdownlist, I updated the database, creating a new column to store the new Level from the enum dropdownlist.

Here is how I was saving the first item (Name) to the database. How can I modify this code to capture the enum dropdownlist selection and write both the Name and the Level to the database table?

```
// Create: POST
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(ClassGroup newclass)
    {
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {                
            db.ClassGroups.Add(newclass);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Here's what I tried with no success:

```
// Create: POST
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(ClassGroup newClass, ClassTypeEnum addLevel)
    {
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        { 
            db.ClassGroups.Add(newClass);
            db.ClassGroups.Add(addLevel);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View();
    }
```

And just in case you need to see the enum dropdownlist:

```
div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Level, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(x => x.Level,  new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Level, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

Any help to a MVC newbie is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

My full classGroup looks like this:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Amos.Models
{
    public class ClassGroup
    {
        [Required]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Name / Alias")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public ClassTypeEnum Level{ get; set; }

        public enum ClassTypeEnum
        {
            Junior = 0,
            Kindergarten = 1,
            Primary = 2 
        }

    }
```

Comment: What does your `ClassGroup` class look like?

Comment: You do not need to change anything (assuming the `ClassGroup` contains the `public ClassTypeEnum Level { get; set; }` property

Comment: @StephenMuecke Does it work if the underlying database column type is textual vs numeric? Does it matter if it's database-first or code-first?

Comment: The column will be `int` (assuming you have code first and have done the migrations) If you want to store it as a `string` then you can use workarounds such as [this](https://justsimplycode.com/2016/01/17/storing-enum-as-string-in-entity-framework-6/). But it would be simpler to make the data model proeprty a string, and your view model property the `enum` and just parse the value when mapping.

Comment: @maccettura - I just posted the ClassGroup

Comment: @StephenMuecke - I do need to change something because it is not working. The new Level is not getting created in the database. After I click my create button, it doesnt even go to the Index page. Yes, column in db is int. Yes I've done the migrations.

Comment: The model and view code look fine. Have you checked the value of `newClass.Level` in the POST method to ensure it is being correctly bound? (note that the `ClassTypeEnum addLevel` parameter and the `db.ClassGroups.Add(addLevel);` line of code need to be deleted

Comment: @StephenMuecke - Good question, how do I check it? Can I view the value on the screen? I will also look at the post to linked to for workarounds.

Comment: I meant put a break point in the first line of the `[HttpPost]` method and check what the value of `newClass.Level` is when you submit the form. Is it being bound correctly?

Comment: @StephenMuecke - I've deleted the ClassTypeEnum addLevel parameter and the db.ClassGroups.Add(addLevel);. Can I save both Name and Level just using the one newClass parameter?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: @StephenMuecke - I tried the breakpoint but I doesnt seem to give me anything. Perhaps it isn't being bound correctly. But when I was just adding Name to the database, the code worked perfectly. Its the adding of the enum value that I'm not getting

Comment: Should I be looking at converting enum to a string and then saving it to the database?

Comment: No, that is not necessary. It makes no sense that you claim you do not get a value, so not sure what else you might be doing wrong in the view

Comment: @StephenMuecke - what I meant was I set the break point, run the code and the code doesn't actually break on it own. I didn't mention that I'm also a bit new to Visual Studio :) So the chance that I'm doing it wrong is high